# the meaning of expression attribute value surrounded by sigle quotes

Tags: spring-webflow

all

I often see the expression attribute value surrounded by sigle quotes like this in the Flow Defenition XML file.

```
<evaluate expression="'proceed'" />
```

Would you like to tell me the meaning of the expression?

Answer (score 2):

it means it's the string `"proceed"`, and not the name of a bean or an action.